# Boolean Algebra POS of $F(A,B,C,D)=\bar{B}A(\bar{C}D+\bar{B})+(B\bigoplus C)$

Tags: real-analysis, boolean-algebra

I need to find SOP and POS of: $F(A,B,C,D)=\bar{B}A(\bar{C}D+\bar{B})+(B\bigoplus C)$.

I found the SOP, but I struggle with the POS of this one.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to start?

Thanks, I appreciate that!

Comment: Once you have the SOP, you can always get the POS from that: keep distributing the OR over AND

Comment: @Bram28 Sounds good! DO you have an example so I can understand more? Thanks!

Comment: Sure!  Simple example:  AB + CD = (A+CD)(B+CD) = (A+C)(A+D)(B+C)(B+D) .... which you can also do in just one step (it's really just the algebraic FOIL principle ... but it generalizes to any number of disjuncts with any number of conjuncts

Comment: @Bram28 I wondered what SOP and POS meant, but your comment clarified that they mean DNF and CNF, respectively.

Comment: @Bram28 Great! Thank you for that! :)

Comment: @AndreasBlass What? I am teaching AndreasBlass something?  That's a first! :P   Anyway, yes, computer engineers like to use the + and . notation, and as such they talk about SOP (Sum of Products) and POS (Product of Sums) :)

Answer (score 2):

$$F(A,B,C,D)=B'A(C'D+B')+(B\oplus C)\\
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow B'A(C'D+B')+B'C+BC'\\
\Longrightarrow B'(C+AB'+AC'D)+BC'\\
$$
Using elimination and a factoring theorem:
$$
(X+Y)(X'+Z)=XZ+X'Y
$$
we have
$$
\Longrightarrow (B+C+A+AC'D)(B'+C')\\
\Longrightarrow (A+B+C)(B'+C')\\
$$
Noting that $X+YY'=X$
$$
\Longrightarrow (A+B+C+DD')(AA'+B'+C'+DD')
$$
Also $(X+YZ)=(X+Y)(X+Z)$
$$
\Longrightarrow (A+B+C+D)(A+B+C+D')(A+B'+C'+D')(A+B'+C'+D)(A'+B'+C'+D')(A'+B'+C'+D)
$$

Comment: Thank you mate, unfortunately this is not POS you ended up with, but I will try take it from there, thanks!

Comment: @CalculusLover if you may, please point out my mistake, or can you send me the required POS ? I'd love to learn from it

Comment: Sure: $ ( +  +  + )( +  +  + ̅)( + ̅ + ̅+ )( + ̅ + ̅
+ ̅)(̅+ ̅ + ̅+ )(̅+ ̅ + ̅+ ̅)$

Comment: @CalculusLover oh is that what you meant, I earlier assumed that you want a minimal POS, I've edited the last part in regards to that